# Undefined value for select in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I simply want to set the undefined value for select. By undefined I mean "undefined" one but not only default one.

I have this:

```
= form_for @address do |f|
  = f.select :country_id, [['no country selected','0']] + Country.as_key_value_array
```

where `Country.as_key_value_array` returns an array of `[['country1','1'], ['country2','3'],['country3','3']]`

Is there any other way to reach what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.select :country_id, "<option value='0'>no country selected</option>".html_safe + options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name)`

Answer (score 0):

check this out,

```
= f.select :country_id, options_for_select([['no country selected','0']] + Country.as_key_value_array)
```